# IBM Mobile Test Workbench Performance Parameters not found

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

When I am running test from Mobile Test Workbench Workspace, I am not able to see Resource monitoring or other performance parameter in Run Configuration dialog box.

I am using 8.7 MobileFirst Rational Test Workbench

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question whether or not you have properly enabled Resource Monitoring. This feature is meant to be enabled as described in the following user documentation topic: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_8.6.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.moeb.doc/topics/t_run_wb.html

> Resource monitoring starts immediately after the test run is
>   initiated. Resource data is collected at the frequency specified in
>   the polling interval. At every interval the collected data is averaged
>   for resources and sent back to workbench to be plotted in the report.
>   Resource monitoring is terminated when the test run finishes.
>
> Procedure From the test workbench, you can initiate the running of a
>   mobile test by using any of the following steps in the Test Workbench
>   perspective: In the Test Navigator view, right-click a test and click
>   Run As > Test. From the Test Navigator view, open the test and, in the
>   test editor, click the Run button.
>
> Add the mobile test to the Compound Test editor. A wizard displays the
>   list of available devices. Select the device on which the test will be
>   run.